# Read all bookmarks from a PDF document and create a dictionary with PageNumber and Title of the bookmark

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I a trying to read a PDF document using Python with PyPDF2 package. The objective is to read all the bookmarks in the pdf and construct a dictionary with page numbers of the bookmark as keys and titles of bookmarks as values.

There is not much support on the internet on how to achieve it except for [this](https://medium.com/@menglishu09/get-bookmarks-from-pdf-using-pypdf2-4166ae8eb6f6) article. The code posted in it doesn't work and i am not an expert in python to correct it. PyPDF2's reader object has a property named **outlines** which gives you a list of all bookmark objects but there are no page numbers for bookmarks and traversing the list is little difficult as there are no parent/child relationships between bookmarks.

I am sharing below my code to read a pdf document and inspect **outlines** property.

```py
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('SomeDocument.pdf')

print(reader.numPages)
print(reader.outlines[1][1])
```

Answer (score 10):

The parent/child relationships are preserved by having the lists nested in each other. This sample code will display bookmarks recursively as an indented table of contents:

```
import PyPDF2


def show_tree(bookmark_list, indent=0):
    for item in bookmark_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # recursive call with increased indentation
            show_tree(item, indent + 4)
        else:
            print(" " * indent + item.title)


reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("[your filename]")

show_tree(reader.getOutlines())
```

I don't know how to retrieve the page numbers. I tried with a few files, and the `page` attribute of a `Destination` object is always an instance of `IndirectObject`, which doesn't seem to contain any information about page number.

**UPDATE:**

There is a [getDestinationPageNumber](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader.getDestinationPageNumber) method to get page numbers from `Destination` objects. Modified code to create your desired dictionary:

```
import PyPDF2


def bookmark_dict(bookmark_list):
    result = {}
    for item in bookmark_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # recursive call
            result.update(bookmark_dict(item))
        else:
            result[reader.getDestinationPageNumber(item)] = item.title
    return result


reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("[your filename]")

print(bookmark_dict(reader.getOutlines()))
```

However, note that you will overwrite and lose some values if there are multiple bookmarks on the same page (dictionary keys must be unique).

Comment: Notice that most methods are "now" deprecated and have been renamed but the error traceback tells how to correct, see for ex doc of [`outline`](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/PdfReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfReader.outline)

Comment: Use the bookmark's name as key (which suppose to be unique). To retrieve the page number use `item.page`.  Then add the terms in the dictionary with `result[item.title] = item.page`

Comment: UPDATE : 

`outline = reader.outline`
`show_tree = show_tree(outline)`
`print(show_tree)`

Comment: an update for deprecated functions of PyPDF2:

def bookmark_dict(bookmark_list):
    result = []
    for item in bookmark_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # recursive call
            result.extend(bookmark_dict(item))
        else:
            result.append({'PageNumber': reader.get_destination_page_number(item),
                           'Title': item.title})
    return result

Answer (score 7):

edit: **PyPDF2 is not dead!** I'm the new maintainer.

edit: **PyPDF2 moved to pypdf** I'm now also the maintainer of that project

### Using pypdf

This is an updated / improved verson of [mportes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54363890/562769):

```py
from typing import Dict, Union

from pypdf import PdfReader


def bookmark_dict(
    bookmark_list, reader: PdfReader, use_labels: bool = False,
) -> Dict[Union[str, int], str]:
    """
    Extract all bookmarks as a flat dictionary.

    Args:
        bookmark_list: The reader.outline or a recursive call
        use_labels: If true, use page labels. If False, use page indices.

    Returns:
        A dictionary mapping page labels (or page indices) to their title

    Examples:
        Download the PDF from https://zenodo.org/record/50395 to give it a try
    """
    result = {}
    for item in bookmark_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # recursive call
            result.update(bookmark_dict(item, reader))
        else:
            page_index = reader.get_destination_page_number(item)
            page_label = reader.page_labels[page_index]
            if use_labels:
                result[page_label] = item.title
            else:
                result[page_index] = item.title
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reader = PdfReader("GeoTopo-A5.pdf")
    bms = bookmark_dict(reader.outline, reader, use_labels=True)

    for page_nb, title in sorted(bms.items(), key=lambda n: f"{str(n[0]):>5}"):
        print(f"{page_nb:>3}: {title}")
```

### My old  answer

Here is how you do it with PyMupdf and [type annotations](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/type-annotations-in-python-3-8-3b401384403d):

```py
from typing import Dict

import fitz  # pip install pymupdf


def get_bookmarks(filepath: str) -> Dict[int, str]:
    # WARNING! One page can have multiple bookmarks!
    bookmarks = {}
    with fitz.open(filepath) as doc:
        toc = doc.getToC()  # [[lvl, title, page, …], …]
        for level, title, page in toc:
            bookmarks[page] = title
    return bookmarks


print(get_bookmarks("my.pdf"))
```

Comment: `getToC` is now deprecated ->  [`get_toc`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.get_toc)

Comment: quite fun, I used PyPDF2 to edit a pdf with bookmarks and I am testing if everything is right. With PyPDF2 (answer of _mportes_) it shows them properly but with `fitz` `get_toc` returns an empty list

Comment: @cards Thanks for the hint. I've just created an updated version of mportes answer. You should use `pypdf` and not `PyPDF2`

Comment: I wasn't aware of it! I found very confusing all the `PyPDFX` changing in the last years... Thanks anyway for your work! Here the link with [history](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/history.html) of the project available in the doc

Comment: And how can you extract the content of each page?

Comment: `page.extract_text()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'PdfReader' object has no attribute 'page_labels'

Comment: Are you using `pypdf>=3.3.0`? We are at `pypdf==3.11.1`

Comment: You also just introduced me to F-string formatting. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Thoma about the `pypdf` implementation: I really don't like the dependency from the global `reader`... my 1st reimplementation was to execute the recursive part in another function body together with a small refactor... but again not satisfied. Then I start digging a bit and I could get read the `reader` dependency with `item.page.pdf`, is this a reliable alternative?

Comment: @cards Thanks for pointing it out! I've adjusted the answer to pass `reader` as an argument.

Comment: The `PageObject.pdf` could be None. I'm not entirely sure if it is always set.

Answer (score 2):

an update to @mportes answer due to deprecated functions:

```
    def bookmark_dict(bookmark_list, reader):
        result = []
        for item in bookmark_list:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                # recursive call
                result.extend(bookmark_dict(item, reader))
            else:
                result.append({'PageNumber': reader.get_destination_page_number(item),
                               'Title': item.title})
        return result
    
    
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    
    bookmarks = bookmark_dict(reader.outline, reader)
    bkmarks_df = pd.DataFrame(bookmarks)
    print(bkmarks_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

@myrmica provides the correct answer.  The function needs some additional error handling to handle a situation where a bookmark is defective.  I've also added 1 to the page numbers because they are zero-based.

```
import PyPDF2

def bookmark_dict(bookmark_list):
    result = {}
    for item in bookmark_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            # recursive call
            result.update(bookmark_dict(item))
        else:
          try:
             result[reader.getDestinationPageNumber(item)+1] = item.title
          except:
             pass
    return result

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("[your filename]")

print(bookmark_dict(reader.getOutlines()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I based my solution off another one here, with some mods to make it support multiple bookmarks per page and include parent info.

Also, instead of just creating a dictionary with results, I also include an example use. In this case, a simple program that copies a PDF with bookmarks. That way, you can see how the bookmarks are extracted into a dict, and also how to use that dict in a practical application.

One note: I chose to use hash values as an ID for each bookmark, to identify the parents for nesting. It was a choice...  Here's the code:

```
import sys
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def bookmark_dict(bookmark_list, reader, **kw):
    """
    Extract all bookmarks as a flat dictionary.
    Args:
        bookmark_list: The reader.outline or a recursive call
        reader: a PdfReader object required for certain functionality
    KWArgs:
        result: the dictionary starting point (to prevent overwrite)
        parent: the parent of a list
        use_labels: use page labels if True, otherwise use page indices.
    Returns:
        A dictionary mapping page labels (or page indices) to their titles,
            with parent/nesting info
    """
    result = kw.get('result', {})
    parent = kw.get('parent', None)
    use_labels = kw.get('use_labels', False)
    for item in bookmark_list: # each item is a dict-like obj or a list
        if isinstance(item, list): # a list is for the children of last item
            bookmark_dict(item, reader, use_labels=use_labels, result=result, parent=hash_value)
        else:
            page_index = reader.get_destination_page_number(item)
            page_label = reader.page_labels[page_index]
            key = page_label if use_labels else page_index
            if key not in result:
                result[key] = []
            hash_value = item.hash_value()
            result[key].append(dict(bid=hash_value, title=item.title, page=key, zoom=item.zoom, top=item.top, left=item.left, children_b=item.has_children(), children=list(item.children()), parent=parent))
    return result

def copy_pdf_with_bookmarks(infile, outfile):
    reader = PdfReader(infile)
    writer = PdfWriter()
    for page in reader.pages:
        writer.add_page(page)
    bookmark_d = bookmark_dict(reader.outline, reader)
    mapping_d = {} # bid to obj
    for page, bookmarks in bookmark_d.items(): #: # 
        for bm in bookmarks:
            if (bm_parent := bm['parent']) is None or bm_parent in mapping_d:
                parent_obj = mapping_d.get(bm_parent, None)
            else:
                print(f"{bm_parent=} NOT FOUND in {mapping_d=}")
            obj = writer.add_outline_item(bm['title'], bm['page'], parent=parent_obj)
            if bm['bid'] not in mapping_d:
                mapping_d[bm['bid']] = obj
    writer.write(outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        copy_pdf_with_bookmarks(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Although the source file bookmark/outlines info from PyPDF includes top, left, and zoom info, and some other stuff, PyPDF does not seem to allow one to use it when inserting bookmarks/outlines into a PDF.  If I'm missing something, please let me know. I would love to add this extra information to my answer.

As for how the code works: the premise is that you never place an indented/nested bookmark till after the parent has been placed. The *mapping_d* is used to map from the *bid* bookmark ids created/used by the bookmark_dict() routine to the object ids generated by PyPDF.