# Python Retrieve the bookmark structure of a PDF: getting an error

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, bookmarks

I am trying to retrieve the bookmark structure of a PDF, ideally, I also want the hierarchy.

I followed this thread: [Read all bookmarks from a PDF document and create a dictionary with PageNumber and Title of the bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303318/read-all-bookmarks-from-a-pdf-document-and-create-a-dictionary-with-pagenumber-a)

The idea was to use this code as a starting point and then I could adjust it to my needs.

I managed to get it working, but my code often crashes with the following error "( ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)"

> C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Google Drive\python\projects\Get bookmarks.py"

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Google Drive\python\projects\Get bookmarks.py", line 24, in 
> bms = bookmark_dict(reader.outline, use_labels=False)

> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf_reader.py", line 844, in outline
> return self._get_outline()

> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf_reader.py", line 880, in _get_outline
> outline_obj = self._build_outline_item(node)

> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf_reader.py", line 1054, in _build_outline_item
> outline_item = self._build_destination(title, dest)

> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf_reader.py", line 1018, in _build_destination
> return Destination(title, page, Fit(fit_type=typ, fit_args=array))  # type: ignore

> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\generic_data_structures.py", line 1495, in **init**
> (
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

> Process finished with exit code 1

This is the code I'm using (a direct use of the thread mentioned above).

```
from typing import Dict, Union
from pypdf import PdfReader

def bookmark_dict(
        bookmark_list, use_labels: bool = False
) -> Dict[Union[str, int], str]:
    result = {}
    for item in bookmark_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result.update(bookmark_dict(item))
        else:
            page_index = reader.get_destination_page_number(item)
            page_label = reader.page_labels[page_index]
            if use_labels:
                result[page_label] = item.title
            else:
                result[page_index] = item.title
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder ="x:\\"
    file="TestPDF.pdf"
    reader = PdfReader(folder + file)
    bms = bookmark_dict(reader.outline, use_labels=False)
    for page_nb, title in sorted(bms.items(), key=lambda n: f"{str(n[0]):>5}"):
         print(f"{page_nb:>3}: {title}")
```

The PDF file that is giving me an error can be found here: https://easyupload.io/7fsipz

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The file has many malformed bookmarks:

```
cpdf -list-bookmarks-json TestPDF.pdf > foo.json
Warning: Could not read destination G [1 0 R/XYZ 820] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [4 0 R/XYZ 837] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [20 0 R/XYZ 827] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [34 0 R/XYZ 817] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [40 0 R/XYZ 813] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [43 0 R/XYZ 831] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [56 0 R/XYZ 826] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [59 0 R/XYZ 804] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [59 0 R/XYZ 608] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [59 0 R/XYZ 529] 
Warning: Could not read destination G [59 0 R/XYZ 608] 
(many more lines of output)
```

It seems the library you are using doesn't know how to skip them. You can use cpdf as above to get the JSON file of all the bookmarks which are valid.

Edit: I've just fixed cpdf to cope with this malformity.

You'll have to build CamlPDF and CPDF from source to benefit from this change, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try package PyMuPDF. Gives you the TOC in one statement - including hierarchy:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc=fitz.open("input.pdf")
toc = doc.get_toc()
```

Every item in the returned Python list looks like `(lvl, title, page)`,"lvl" being the hierarchy level.

If you want to be pedantic, use `doc.get_toc(simple=False)` which returns extended information including the full link, color of the bookmark, collapse information and more.

You can modify the list as you like BTW and put it back to the PDF via again just one statement `doc.set_toc(toc)`.

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).