How can I extract the PDF section/chapter titles with Python?
I want to add the page titles in the pdf to an array with a loop.I have tried many ways so far but I have not succeeded. How can it be done?
I tried to do it by selecting the first lines on the page, but the sentence in the first line may not be the title. I tried to select the text size based on whether the sentence in the first line is larger than the others or not. But I wasn't successful, maybe I tried wrong.

PDFs are notoriously inconsistent. It'll depend on the actual documents in question. I'd recommend editing your post to include links to sample PDFs. Also, look into pandoc to convert PDF -> markdown, which is more structured and possibly easier to parse

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If the pdf has bookmarks (a table of contents), you can extract it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63519098/562769
Besides that, you can try to write your own logic using font sizes. Pdfminer might work better for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110755/562769
